# How to Create Full Width Figures When Using the "twocolumn" "classoption" for Knitr to PDF?

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr

How can one create a full width figure when using the **twocolumn** class option in knitr / R / RMarkdown / LaTex?

Based on the Knitr documentation, I've tried two approaches. Nothing short of editing the .tex file has worked for me so far.

This:

````
---
output: pdf_document
classoption: twocolumn
header-includes: 
    - \usepackage{lipsum}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\lipsum[1-2]


```{r fig.env = "figure*", fig.cap = "Test"}
plot(runif(10))
```

\lipsum[3-5]

```{r fig.fullwidth = T}
plot(runif(10))
```
````

Results in this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yihui has fixed this in the development version of knitr. Yihui's response:

*The option fig.env = 'figure*' should be respected now (in the dev version of knitr). But the plot will float to a new page. I guess that is a LaTeX issue orthogonal to knitr. Thanks!*

Don't forget that **you must include a caption** for this to work.

````
---
output: pdf_document
classoption: twocolumn
header-includes: 
    - \usepackage{lipsum}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\lipsum[1-3]


```{r fig.env = "figure*"}
plot(runif(10))
```

\lipsum[2]

```{r fig.env = "figure*", fig.cap = ""}
plot(runif(10))
```
\lipsum[2]
````